# Как задать условие для выборки?

Tags: twig

Добрый день.

Пытаюсь создать шаблон для вывода ленты некоторых объектов из БД. Но нужно выбрать не все объекты, а, принадлежащие определенной категории. Каким образом можно задать эту категорию в шаблоне (например, k_categories_id=30) и увидеть существование этого условия при обработке и рендере шаблона?

Спасибо.

Comment: @sslab, выборка не должна производится в шаблоне. Это возможно, но стрелка *нетудаметра* сейчас находится в красной зоне.

Comment: Нет, выборку я не хочу делать в шаблоне. В шаблоне я хочу сказать, что k_categories_id=30, а при обработке шаблона, где то тут
$loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($p);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
я хочу увидеть, проверить, что было задано условие k_categories_id=30 и при последующей выборке данных из БД учесть это условие.

Comment: @sslab, если условие задается в шаблоне, то выборкой, по факту, дирижирует он. В шаблоне нет данных. Никаких. Там есть отображение того, что ему передал вышестоящий уровень. Шаблон может вывести условие, но *задать* его он не может.

Comment: Т.е если у меня шаблон подразумевает вывод объектов из таблицы, коих в таблице миллион, то я в шаблоне не могу указать, что мне нужно делать выборку не по всей таблице, а только выбрать те записи у ктр k_categories_id=30?

Comment: @sslab, этой выборкой должна заниматься БД. Можно, конечно, написать конструкцию

    {% for item in set %}
        {% if item['k_categories_id'] == 30 %}
            {# вывод #}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}

Но это просто убийство ресурсов.

Comment: Я может не правильно выражаюсь. Попытаюсь еще раз сказать.
Я хочу в шаблоне задать условие, чтобы выборка шла не по всей таблице, а лишь по определенному условию в таблице. Выборка не в шаблоне конечно же выполняется, а в скрипте, где формируются данные для шаблона.
То, что в шаблоне можно указать условие и проверять его уже при применении сформированных данных, как указано в примере выше, я знаю, но для этого нужно выбрать миллион записей из таблицы, чтобы вывести 3 строки.

Comment: @sslab нельзя задавать условия выборки из таблицы бд внутри шаблона. Шаблоны предназначены для вывода данных, там не должно быть никаких запросов в бд или что-то с ней связанное